# How to make an array of Set<String>?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, set

I am trying to declare an array of `Set<String>` so I do not have to manage each sets separately. But things go wrong:

```
      ArrayList<Set<String>> categories=new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Here, Java says that type `Set<String>` is erroneous and then reports an error.

If this is wrong, then how can I make an array of :

```
static  Set<String> category1 = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

Comment: A `LinkedHashSet` is not an `ArrayList` of anything.

Comment: I don't think this works.  You have to manage the `Set`s individually.  If that's a pain, make your own ListSet class and encapsulate the management.

Comment: @markspace that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. I dislike to individually manage each set and I thought there is a way to make an array of them so can manage all together?

Comment: I'm like 99.99% sure there is no way to do what you want.  You'll just have to write some code to do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are initialising an ArrayList with  LinkedHashSet object and hence the error:

```
  ArrayList<Set<String>> categories=new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

change it to

```
  ArrayList<Set<String>> categories=new ArrayList<>();
```

you need to use HashSet when you create a Set to be added into the list. Something like this:

```
      Set<String> firstSet = new HashSet<String>();
      //build your set 
      //add set to list
      categories.add(firstSet);
```

Btw, you mentioned Array in your question description, so here is the declaraiton for plain array of Sets:

```
      Set<String>[] categories=new HashSet[10];
```

Comment: But then I have to make all Sets individually which is painful.

Comment: @lonesome It's the only way.  Java doesn't automagically make classes for you like you are envisioning.

Comment: @lonesome You will need to initialize all elements that needed to be added to a collection. They cannot be autoinitialized. To reduce the task, you may write methods to build your Set(s)

Comment: So what is the difference between `Set<String>[]` and ArrayList<Set<String>>?

Comment: @lonesome Read your course book again for difference between arraylist and array

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
List<HashSet> list =new ArrayList<HashSet>();
HashSet<String> hs =new HashSet<String>();
hs.add(value1);
hs.add(value2);
list.add(hs);
```

You can use for or while loop to add values to set(hs) and then add the set to list.